# Iphone string url with parameter value dot(".") not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

```
NSString *lDownloadURL = [NSString
      stringWithFormat:@"https://xxxx.com/tes.php?filename=%@",
                       tUniqueId]; // tUniqueId=1311454454.4270
NSString *result=
 [lDownloadURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Download URL: %@", lDownloadURL); 
[helper download:lDownloadURL];
```

// when im trying to pass this url its showing the follwing error

> Data failed: Invalid URL
>   [https://xxxx.com/tes.php?filename=1311454454.4270]

please help me soon... advance thanks

Comment: How is the `download:` method defined? Does it take an `NSString` instance or `NSURL`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean test.php instead of tes.php?

Comment: that download accept string url. the problem is parameter ie( filename) it contains value with "."  ..... i used the same download method for another its working fine ie without dot in parameter...

Comment: sorry that spell mistake its "test.php"